# My quicksort hangs for list of size 2^13

Tags: python, stack-overflow, quicksort, tail-recursion

I've written a quicksort function in python as follows.

```
def quickSort1(A,p,q):
    if p < q:
        pivotIndex = partition(A,p,q)
        quickSort1(A,p,pivotIndex-1)
        quickSort1(A,pivotIndex+1,q)
def partition(A,first, last):
    pivot = A[first]
    tooBig = first+1
    tooSmall = last
    while True:
        while tooBig<=last and A[tooBig]<pivot:
            tooBig+=1
        while tooSmall>first and A[tooSmall]>pivot:
            tooSmall-=1
        if tooBig < tooSmall:
            temp = A[tooBig]
            A[tooBig] = A[tooSmall]
            A[tooSmall] = temp
        else:
            break
    A[first] = A[tooSmall]
    A[tooSmall] = pivot
    return tooSmall
```

I'm testing the algorithm's execution time with varying sizes of lists (from 2 to 2^16). For example,

```
n = 2**13
s = [random.randint(-65536,65536) for i in range(n)]
#Begin Regular Quick Sort test with unsorted list
setup = '''
gc.enable()
from __main__ import quickSort1
from __main__ import n
from __main__ import s
            '''
 average = sum(timeit.Timer('A=s[:]; quickSort1(A,0,len(A)-1)',setup = setup).repeat(1,10))/10
```

I've verified that the algorithm works correctly for smaller sizes, but once I reach 2^13, the program hangs. I've tried doing `sys.setrecursionlimit(2**30)`, but this doesn't change anything. Is there something wrong with my algorithm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there's an error in your logic.  If **partition** receives a sub-list in which A[tooBig] == A[tooSmall], then both of your **while** loop conditions are **False** from the start, and the **if** swaps equal values.  Nothing changes, and you're stuck in an infinite loop.

I've managed to reproduce this with 2**12 often enough: the problem arises when your **n** gets large enough that matching endpoints is a likely occurrence.

In case it helps, here's the code I used to trace the problem -- it's all yours with a few **print** insertions and **indent** to help trace teh call depth.

```
indent = ""

def quickSort1(A,p,q):
    global indent
    print indent, "ENTER", p, q
    indent += "  "

    if p < q:
        pivotIndex = partition(A,p,q)
        quickSort1(A,p,pivotIndex-1)
        quickSort1(A,pivotIndex+1,q)
    indent = indent[2:]
    print indent, "LEAVE"


def partition(A,first, last):
    print indent, "  PART", first, last
    pivot = A[first]
    tooBig = first+1
    tooSmall = last
    while True:
        if abs(tooSmall-tooBig) < 10:
            print indent, tooSmall, tooBig, A[tooBig:tooSmall+1]
        while tooBig<=last and A[tooBig]<pivot:
            tooBig+=1
        while tooSmall>first and A[tooSmall]>pivot:
            tooSmall-=1
        if tooBig < tooSmall:
            temp = A[tooBig]
            A[tooBig] = A[tooSmall]
            A[tooSmall] = temp
        else:
            break
    A[first] = A[tooSmall]
    A[tooSmall] = pivot
    print indent, "  PART", tooSmall
    return tooSmall
```

The most common loop is when the list gets down to two equal values.  Here's a longer one:

```
2030 2022 [-32421, -32303, -32723, -32402, -32705, -32269, -32422, -32834, -32421]
```

Comment: Ah ha! Yes, to expand on your solution- when the elements at position tooBig, tooSmall and the pivot element value are all equal, then there is an infinite loop because as you said the two while loops are always false, and when the value are swapped it doesn't change anything because they are the same. I fixed this by changing the pivot comparisons to <= and >=. The algorithm now works for all sizes of n. Thank you.

Comment: Great!  Yes, the pivot will always start as the first element of the provided sub-list.  In other words, it *must* be equal to A[tooBig] in the first iteration of the **while** loop.  if A[tooSmall] is equal, we're sunk.